# How to show all services in Symfony 3?

Tags: php, symfony

How to show all services in Symfony 3?

I tried:

```
bin/console debug:container --types
```

And ok, this show me services, but for logger is:

> Psr\Log\LoggerInterface                                        alias for "monolog.logger"

but if I would like to use in controller then I must use:

```
$logger = $this->get('logger');
```

(I know - in Symfony 3.3 I can pass LoggerInterface in controller)

For email:

> Swift_Mailer        alias for "swiftmailer.mailer.default"
>   Swift_Spool alias for "swiftmailer.mailer.default.spool.memory"
>   Swift_Transport      alias for "swiftmailer.mailer.default.transport.spool"

But in controller I must use:

```
$mailer = $this->get('mailer');
```

So how can I find what I have to type in the controller to use the service?

Comment: `mailer` and `logger` should exist in the list aswell, for me they're further up: `logger    Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger` and `mailer    alias for "swiftmailer.mailer.default"`. Try `php bin/console container:debug | grep "mailer"`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you launch the command without `--types` like this:

```
bin/console debug:container
```

you can see all services and I can see:

```
mailer      alias for "swiftmailer.mailer.default"
```